# Unable to install Python on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, python

Recently I decided to upgrade from Python 2.7 to Python 3.4 on my Windows 8 laptop. So I uninstalled Py2.7, downloaded the .msi file from python's site and ran it. I found that every installer I tried for both 3.4.1 and 3.4.0 would give me an error saying that part of the installer didn't work. The exact error message is "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A Program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor." I've never had this kind of problem before and certainly not with Python. Does anyone know of a good way to try and debug this? It's persisting across so many installers that I'm sure it has to be something on my system.

EDIT: Thanks for the tip about the log file. It's very large (larger than I'm allowed to post on this site ~320k characters). Here's the bit right after it says 'fatal error'. This is from running the suggested code on the installer for 3.4.1 64 bit.

```
Property(S): X = C:\Python34\Tools\pynche\X\
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {65E6DE48-A358-434D-AA4F-4AF72DB4718F}
Property(S): ProductName = Python 3.4.1
Property(S): ProductCode = {DF32BB9E-3ED8-36B5-A649-E8C845C5F3A2}
Property(S): ProductVersion = 3.4.1150
Property(S): Manufacturer = Python Software Foundation
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): VersionNT = 602
Property(S): WhichUsers = ALL
Property(S): ProductLine = Python34
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\Python34\
Property(S): Tools = C:\Python34\Tools\
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = DlgFont8
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): Progress1 = Install
Property(S): Progress2 = installs
Property(S): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(S): DLLDIR = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): LAUNCHERDIR = C:\Windows\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Users\Jesse\Downloads\
Property(S): DLLs = C:\Python34\DLLs\
Property(S): Lib = C:\Python34\Lib\
Property(S): Lib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\__pycache__\
Property(S): asyncio = C:\Python34\Lib\asyncio\
Property(S): asyncio_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\asyncio\__pycache__\
Property(S): site_packages = C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\
Property(S): idlelib = C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\
Property(S): idlelib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\__pycache__\
Property(S): idle_test = C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\idle_test\
Property(S): idle_test_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\idle_test\__pycache__\
Property(S): Icons = C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\Icons\
Property(S): concurrent = C:\Python34\Lib\concurrent\
Property(S): concurrent_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\concurrent\__pycache__\
Property(S): futures = C:\Python34\Lib\concurrent\futures\
Property(S): futures_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\concurrent\futures\__pycache__\
Property(S): http = C:\Python34\Lib\http\
Property(S): http_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\http\__pycache__\
Property(S): sqlite3 = C:\Python34\Lib\sqlite3\
Property(S): sqlite3_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\sqlite3\__pycache__\
Property(S): test = C:\Python34\Lib\sqlite3\test\
Property(S): test_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\sqlite3\test\__pycache__\
Property(S): html = C:\Python34\Lib\html\
Property(S): html_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\html\__pycache__\
Property(S): lib2to3 = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\
Property(S): lib2to3_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\__pycache__\
Property(S): pgen2 = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\pgen2\
Property(S): pgen2_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\pgen2\__pycache__\
Property(S): tests = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\
Property(S): tests_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\__pycache__\
Property(S): data = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\data\
Property(S): data_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\data\__pycache__\
Property(S): fixers = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\data\fixers\
Property(S): fixers_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\data\fixers\__pycache__\
Property(S): myfixes = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\data\fixers\myfixes\
Property(S): myfixes_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\tests\data\fixers\myfixes\__pycache__\
Property(S): fixes = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\fixes\
Property(S): fixes_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\lib2to3\fixes\__pycache__\
Property(S): tkinter = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\
Property(S): tkinter_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\__pycache__\
Property(S): test1 = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\test\
Property(S): test1_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\test\__pycache__\
Property(S): test_tkinter = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\test\test_tkinter\
Property(S): test_tkinter_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\test\test_tkinter\__pycache__\
Property(S): test_ttk = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\test\test_ttk\
Property(S): test_ttk_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\test\test_ttk\__pycache__\
Property(S): wsgiref = C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\
Property(S): wsgiref_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\wsgiref\__pycache__\
Property(S): venv = C:\Python34\Lib\venv\
Property(S): venv_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\venv\__pycache__\
Property(S): scripts = C:\Python34\Lib\venv\scripts\
Property(S): nt = C:\Python34\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\
Property(S): posix = C:\Python34\Lib\venv\scripts\posix\
Property(S): json = C:\Python34\Lib\json\
Property(S): json_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\json\__pycache__\
Property(S): curses = C:\Python34\Lib\curses\
Property(S): curses_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\curses\__pycache__\
Property(S): multiprocessing = C:\Python34\Lib\multiprocessing\
Property(S): multiprocessing_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\multiprocessing\__pycache__\
Property(S): dummy = C:\Python34\Lib\multiprocessing\dummy\
Property(S): dummy_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\multiprocessing\dummy\__pycache__\
Property(S): ensurepip = C:\Python34\Lib\ensurepip\
Property(S): ensurepip_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\ensurepip\__pycache__\
Property(S): _bundled = C:\Python34\Lib\ensurepip\_bundled\
Property(S): logging = C:\Python34\Lib\logging\
Property(S): logging_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\logging\__pycache__\
Property(S): ctypes = C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\
Property(S): ctypes_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\__pycache__\
Property(S): test2 = C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\test\
Property(S): test2_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\test\__pycache__\
Property(S): macholib = C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\macholib\
Property(S): macholib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\macholib\__pycache__\
Property(S): test3 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\
Property(S): test3_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\__pycache__\
Property(S): test_asyncio = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_asyncio\
Property(S): test_asyncio_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_asyncio\__pycache__\
Property(S): support = C:\Python34\Lib\test\support\
Property(S): support_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\support\__pycache__\
Property(S): capath = C:\Python34\Lib\test\capath\
Property(S): encoded_modules = C:\Python34\Lib\test\encoded_modules\
Property(S): encoded_modules_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\encoded_modules\__pycache__\
Property(S): imghdrdata = C:\Python34\Lib\test\imghdrdata\
Property(S): decimaltestdata = C:\Python34\Lib\test\decimaltestdata\
Property(S): sndhdrdata = C:\Python34\Lib\test\sndhdrdata\
Property(S): tracedmodules = C:\Python34\Lib\test\tracedmodules\
Property(S): tracedmodules_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\tracedmodules\__pycache__\
Property(S): crashers = C:\Python34\Lib\test\crashers\
Property(S): crashers_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\crashers\__pycache__\
Property(S): cjkencodings = C:\Python34\Lib\test\cjkencodings\
Property(S): leakers = C:\Python34\Lib\test\leakers\
Property(S): leakers_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\leakers\__pycache__\
Property(S): subprocessdata = C:\Python34\Lib\test\subprocessdata\
Property(S): subprocessdata_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\subprocessdata\__pycache__\
Property(S): test_json = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_json\
Property(S): test_json_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_json\__pycache__\
Property(S): xmltestdata = C:\Python34\Lib\test\xmltestdata\
Property(S): data1 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\data\
Property(S): audiodata = C:\Python34\Lib\test\audiodata\
Property(S): test_importlib = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\
Property(S): test_importlib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\__pycache__\
Property(S): builtin = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\builtin\
Property(S): builtin_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\builtin\__pycache__\
Property(S): namespace_pkgs = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\
Property(S): module_and_namespace_package = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\module_and_namespace_package\
Property(S): module_and_namespace_package_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\module_and_namespace_package\__pycache__\
Property(S): a_test = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\module_and_namespace_package\a_test\
Property(S): project3 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project3\
Property(S): parent = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project3\parent\
Property(S): child = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project3\parent\child\
Property(S): child_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project3\parent\child\__pycache__\
Property(S): project1 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project1\
Property(S): parent1 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project1\parent\
Property(S): child1 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project1\parent\child\
Property(S): child1_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project1\parent\child\__pycache__\
Property(S): project2 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project2\
Property(S): parent2 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project2\parent\
Property(S): child2 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project2\parent\child\
Property(S): child2_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\project2\parent\child\__pycache__\
Property(S): both_portions = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\both_portions\
Property(S): foo = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\both_portions\foo\
Property(S): foo_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\both_portions\foo\__pycache__\
Property(S): not_a_namespace_pkg = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\not_a_namespace_pkg\
Property(S): foo1 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\not_a_namespace_pkg\foo\
Property(S): foo1_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\not_a_namespace_pkg\foo\__pycache__\
Property(S): portion1 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\portion1\
Property(S): foo2 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\portion1\foo\
Property(S): foo2_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\portion1\foo\__pycache__\
Property(S): portion2 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\portion2\
Property(S): foo3 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\portion2\foo\
Property(S): foo3_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\namespace_pkgs\portion2\foo\__pycache__\
Property(S): frozen = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\frozen\
Property(S): frozen_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\frozen\__pycache__\
Property(S): source = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\source\
Property(S): source_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\source\__pycache__\
Property(S): extension = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\extension\
Property(S): extension_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\extension\__pycache__\
Property(S): import_ = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\import_\
Property(S): import__pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_importlib\import_\__pycache__\
Property(S): test_email = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_email\
Property(S): test_email_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_email\__pycache__\
Property(S): data2 = C:\Python34\Lib\test\test_email\data\
Property(S): turtledemo = C:\Python34\Lib\turtledemo\
Property(S): turtledemo_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\turtledemo\__pycache__\
Property(S): xml = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\
Property(S): xml_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\__pycache__\
Property(S): dom = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\dom\
Property(S): dom_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\dom\__pycache__\
Property(S): etree = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\etree\
Property(S): etree_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\etree\__pycache__\
Property(S): parsers = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\parsers\
Property(S): parsers_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\parsers\__pycache__\
Property(S): sax = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\sax\
Property(S): sax_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\xml\sax\__pycache__\
Property(S): email = C:\Python34\Lib\email\
Property(S): email_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\email\__pycache__\
Property(S): mime = C:\Python34\Lib\email\mime\
Property(S): mime_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\email\mime\__pycache__\
Property(S): urllib = C:\Python34\Lib\urllib\
Property(S): urllib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\urllib\__pycache__\
Property(S): encodings = C:\Python34\Lib\encodings\
Property(S): encodings_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\
Property(S): pydoc_data = C:\Python34\Lib\pydoc_data\
Property(S): pydoc_data_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\pydoc_data\__pycache__\
Property(S): msilib = C:\Python34\Lib\msilib\
Property(S): msilib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\msilib\__pycache__\
Property(S): xmlrpc = C:\Python34\Lib\xmlrpc\
Property(S): xmlrpc_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\xmlrpc\__pycache__\
Property(S): unittest = C:\Python34\Lib\unittest\
Property(S): unittest_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\unittest\__pycache__\
Property(S): test4 = C:\Python34\Lib\unittest\test\
Property(S): test4_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\unittest\test\__pycache__\
Property(S): testmock = C:\Python34\Lib\unittest\test\testmock\
Property(S): testmock_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\unittest\test\testmock\__pycache__\
Property(S): collections = C:\Python34\Lib\collections\
Property(S): collections_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\collections\__pycache__\
Property(S): importlib = C:\Python34\Lib\importlib\
Property(S): importlib_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\importlib\__pycache__\
Property(S): distutils = C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\
Property(S): distutils_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\__pycache__\
Property(S): command = C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\command\
Property(S): command_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\command\__pycache__\
Property(S): tests1 = C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\tests\
Property(S): tests1_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\tests\__pycache__\
Property(S): dbm = C:\Python34\Lib\dbm\
Property(S): dbm_pycache = C:\Python34\Lib\dbm\__pycache__\
Property(S): include = C:\Python34\include\
Property(S): libs = C:\Python34\libs\
Property(S): tcl = C:\Python34\tcl\
Property(S): tk8.6 = C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6\
Property(S): ttk = C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6\ttk\
Property(S): msgs = C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6\msgs\
Property(S): images = C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6\images\
Property(S): demos = C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6\demos\
Property(S): images1 = C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6\demos\images\
Property(S): tix8.4.3 = C:\Python34\tcl\tix8.4.3\
Property(S): pref = C:\Python34\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\
Property(S): demos1 = C:\Python34\tcl\tix8.4.3\demos\
Property(S): samples = C:\Python34\tcl\tix8.4.3\demos\samples\
Property(S): bitmaps = C:\Python34\tcl\tix8.4.3\demos\bitmaps\
Property(S): bitmaps1 = C:\Python34\tcl\tix8.4.3\bitmaps\
Property(S): thread2.7.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\thread2.7.0\
Property(S): tdbcsqlite1.0.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\tdbcsqlite1.0.0\
Property(S): tdbcpostgres1.0.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\tdbcpostgres1.0.0\
Property(S): tdbcodbc1.0.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\tdbcodbc1.0.0\
Property(S): tdbcmysql1.0.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\tdbcmysql1.0.0\
Property(S): tdbc1.0.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\tdbc1.0.0\
Property(S): tcl8.6 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\
Property(S): tzdata = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\
Property(S): US = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\US\
Property(S): Pacific = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Pacific\
Property(S): SystemV = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\SystemV\
Property(S): Mexico = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Mexico\
Property(S): Indian = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Indian\
Property(S): Europe = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Europe\
Property(S): Etc = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Etc\
Property(S): Chile = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Chile\
Property(S): Canada = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Canada\
Property(S): Atlantic = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Atlantic\
Property(S): Brazil = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Brazil\
Property(S): Australia = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Australia\
Property(S): Asia = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Asia\
Property(S): Arctic = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Arctic\
Property(S): Antarctica = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Antarctica\
Property(S): America = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\America\
Property(S): North_Dakota = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\America\North_Dakota\
Property(S): Kentucky = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\America\Kentucky\
Property(S): Indiana = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\America\Indiana\
Property(S): Argentina = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\America\Argentina\
Property(S): Africa = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata\Africa\
Property(S): opt0.4 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\opt0.4\
Property(S): msgs1 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\msgs\
Property(S): http1.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\http1.0\
Property(S): encoding = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6\encoding\
Property(S): tcl8 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\
Property(S): _8.6 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.6\
Property(S): tdbc = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.6\tdbc\
Property(S): _8.5 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.5\
Property(S): _8.4 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.4\
Property(S): platform = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.4\platform\
Property(S): _8.3 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.3\
Property(S): _8.2 = C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8\8.2\
Property(S): sqlite33.8.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\sqlite33.8.0\
Property(S): reg1.3 = C:\Python34\tcl\reg1.3\
Property(S): itcl4.0.0 = C:\Python34\tcl\itcl4.0.0\
Property(S): dde1.4 = C:\Python34\tcl\dde1.4\
Property(S): i18n = C:\Python34\Tools\i18n\
Property(S): i18n_pycache = C:\Python34\Tools\i18n\__pycache__\
Property(S): pynche = C:\Python34\Tools\pynche\
Property(S): pynche_pycache = C:\Python34\Tools\pynche\__pycache__\
Property(S): Scripts = C:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\
Property(S): Scripts_pycache = C:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\__pycache__\
Property(S): Doc = C:\Python34\Doc\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): MenuDir = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.4\
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = REMOVEOLDSNAPSHOT;REMOVEOLDVERSION;TARGETDIR;DLLDIR;LAUNCHERDIR
Property(S): WindowsFolder_x86_VC.AFA96EB4_FA9F_335C_A7CB_36079407553D = C:\Windows\
Property(S): SystemFolder_x86_VC.AFA96EB4_FA9F_335C_A7CB_36079407553D = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): DirectoryTable100_x86.AFA96EB4_FA9F_335C_A7CB_36079407553D = DirectoryTable
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\Jesse\Downloads\log.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {32A3290B-8A39-4C7C-83A9-90DFDF2A7FAD}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): RestrictedUserControl = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\Jesse\Downloads
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 5572
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SECONDSEQUENCE = 1
Property(S): ADDLOCAL = DefaultFeature,SharedCRT,Extensions,TclTk,Documentation,Tools,pip_feature,Testsuite,PrependPath
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 602
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9200
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): MsiNTSuitePersonal = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\Jesse\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 4043
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 5839
Property(S): LogonUser = Jesse
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1182483876-2045043420-405903354-1001
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = MINICHROME
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 12:14:36
Property(S): Date = 6/19/2014
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.17929
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.2.9200.16384
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = Jesse
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\522b8.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\Jesse\Downloads\python-3.4.1.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 5
Property(S): Preselected = 1
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\Jesse\Downloads\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {DF32BB9E-3ED8-36B5-A649-E8C845C5F3A2}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:36:539]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:539]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:539]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (60:64) [12:14:36:554]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (60:F0) [12:14:36:554]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (C4:E8) [12:14:36:554]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (C4:E8) [12:14:36:554]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (C4:E8) [12:14:36:554]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 12:14:36: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (C4:E8) [12:14:36:554]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 12:14:36: FatalError. 
Action start 12:14:36: FatalError.
Action 12:14:36: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 12:14:37: FatalError. Return value 2.
```

Comment: First thing to try is creating an installer log file: [`msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.txt`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130758/1030702)

Comment: Did you check the md5 of the installer ? As you can see [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-341/), you should get : "2BK7D-EP51I-EL75P-AP71M".

Comment: just checked, it's a match

Comment: I think the portion of the log *before* the error is more relevant. After the error is just cleanup (rollbacks, etc.).

Comment: Maybe post the whole log to https://gist.github.com? You can also see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/01/446328.aspx) for related advice, if a little dated. Also, please ping me in a comment if you want me to get a notification to check again.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for the advice, here a link to the full log https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/f426846798442f2c8cc0/raw/log.txt

Answer (score 5):

Since this problem comes from that pip comes with python 3.4 installer, you can simply uncheck  the pip install option in the installer and try to install pip manually later.

Comment: This is what worked for me (Windows 7, 32 bit). I first tried to [give the "Everyone" user full access to my temp folder](http://superuser.com/a/526480/313690), but it didn't work. I undid those permissions, unchecked "pip" in the installer, and it worked.

Comment: Just Uncheck "PIP" in the installer. It worked for me as well.

Comment: This plus removing references to PYTHONHOME and Python in the PATH . I installed PIP separately later.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same or at least similar error, but I couldn't find a solution. I had just uninstalled Python 3.4.1 and was trying to install Python 3.4.2.

I tracked down three different issues in my environment, but #3 is what really fixed my issue. The first two items didn't make much difference for my situation, I just included them as additional options/ideas for others (particularly when installing a second Python version, etc.).

1. **Left-over environment variables.**
   I had environment variables from the 3.4.1 installation set. When installing multiple versions, this can cause an error during installation. You may need to remove these environment variables.

   [image]
2. **System PATH.**
   Python was still in the system PATH. Again, when installing multiple versions, this can cause an error during installation. You may need to remove these entries from your PATH.

   [image]
3. **The actual problem: Custom `open/command` in the Registry.**
   I have this registry entry here, (plus adding `.PY` to the `PATHEXT` envar), so I can run Python programs using only `app.py`, instead of having to type in `PYTHON app.py`.

   [image]

The problem was that the new version of Python was getting partially installed and then it was trying to run some Python commands during the installation. Because of my custom registration, it was trying to run the Python code using the old path to python.exe, which was of course uninstalled. So, it would fail every time.

So, removing the custom open/command allowed the installation to succeed. I added it back in, once the installation was completed.

A couple things to note. I wouldn't have had the problem if I wasn't changing the installation location. And, I could have just updated the open/command entry to point to the new location instead of removing it and re-adding it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Hooray, Finally after lats of investigation I find the solution,
Go to the system path and remove any path address which point to python27 or any other version
and run the msi installer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a concrete answer here, but here's a few rather generic MSI debugging steps that can narrow down the issue:

First, we need to generate a log of the installation. The command `msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.txt` can do that.

Once you have the log, it's the first thing you can do is search for `Error` or `FatalError` (as you did do). Note that this occurs in the log *after* the rollback actions, so you'll need to scroll back up past many pages of `FileRemove`, `ComponentUnregister`, etc.. In fact, you might find searching for `InstallFinalize` and looking directly above that to be more useful (ignore the first occurrence near the top).

Here are the interesting lines from your error log:

```
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:22:868]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=UpdatePip,,)
Action 12:14:22: UpdatePip. 
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:22:868]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=UpdatePip,ActionType=3090,Source=C:\Python34\python.exe,Target=-m ensurepip -U --default-pip,)
CustomAction UpdatePip returned actual error code 3 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:23:212]: Note: 1: 1722 2: UpdatePip 3: C:\Python34\python.exe 4: -m ensurepip -U --default-pip 
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:23:212]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action UpdatePip, location: C:\Python34\python.exe, command: -m ensurepip -U --default-pip 
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:25:627]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (60:80) [12:14:25:627]: Product: Python 3.4.1 -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action UpdatePip, location: C:\Python34\python.exe, command: -m ensurepip -U --default-pip
```

This is an interesting error, and I am not entirely sure why `python -m ensurepip -U --default-pip` would be failing. I would suggest perhaps trying to grab a portable copy or compiling from source and then running the command manually, to see if you can get more information. Failing that, you might try contacting the maintainers via [IRC](https://www.python.org/community/irc/), [a mailing list](https://www.python.org/community/lists/) or some other method.

And, of course, if you do figure out why please post a self-answer here to help others!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem came down to the Python installer finding the wrong version of hashlib on my system, which in turn broke the 'ensurepip' step in the installation, which unfortunately fails to report a useful error. Generating the msiexec log helped me track down that error.

It seems the installer should be more careful to use its own hashlib.

[This bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue22028) is related, and [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575598/python-attributeerror-with-hashlib-no-such-attribute-openssl-md-meth-names) is what helped me figure out that it was an extraneous hashlib (although my problem was on Windows).