Can't update or remove TortoiseGit
I'm trying to upgrade TortoiseGit from version 2.15 to 2.16 on Windows 11, but the installer fails with a message:

There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.

When trying to remove or repair, I get the same error message. The detailed message from the installer log is:
Action 08:58:44: UnregisterSparsePackage.

Action start 08:58:44: UnregisterSparsePackage.
 
CustomAction UnregisterSparsePackage returned actual error code 1157
(note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside 
sandbox)

Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A 
DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your 
support personnel or package vendor.  Action UnregisterSparsePackage, 
entry: UnregisterSparsePackage, library: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI623.tmp

MSI (s) (48:90) [08:58:46:096]: Product: TortoiseGit 2.15.0.0 (64 bit) 
-- Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A 
DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your 
support personnel or package vendor.  Action UnregisterSparsePackage, 
entry: UnregisterSparsePackage, library: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI623.tmp
    
Action ended 08:58:46: UnregisterSparsePackage. Return value 3.

Action ended 08:58:46: INSTALL. Return value 3.

I noticed references to version 2.15, but don't know if that is relevant, and also tried to do a repair with the 2.15 installer; judging by the logs, files are copied, registry entries are written, etc., but at the end, the same error is raised, with the exact same lines in the logfile
I've found a few similar, but not quite the same, problems here and here, and Procmon doesn't reveal anything useful, at least no apparent missing DLL's.
Has anyone seen this particular problem, or know if there is a way to force a clean install?

Are you running the installer with elevated permissions that allow it access to the required Temp folders? https://superuser.com/questions/478631/dll-could-not-be-run-for-msi-installers

@music2myear Yes, I run it from an elevated command prompt

Your issue is NOT connected to a version of the Visual C++ Redistributable, if that was the problem, you could just manually install it. You are unable to uninstall the software, because the installer used to uninstall the software, has either been intentionally or unintentionally been deleted. To diagnose the missing file you would have to look at the log file created by the temporary MSI installer MSI19E5.tmp the files are likely in the same folder as the installer.

@Ramhound okay, is there a way to fix that?

Provide the log from the temporary installer in order to diagnose the problem. You can probably extract the temporary installer from the primary installer and run it yourself.

@Ramhound I added more lines from the logfile. Not sure what the temporary installer is, when I extract all files from the msi, I get another (smaller) msi, and a Program Files folder. When running that 2nd msi, it gives the same error
